# Why does SW4STM32 subdir.mk generate errors?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, stm32

My problem is that I can't compile even the simplest program. I'm using SW4STM32 and STM32F411 Discovery board. The error seems to be in subdir.mk. When I try to compile I keep getting those 13 errors. I tried cleaning and rebuilding it but it doesn't work. I  also reinstalled STM32CubeMX and SW4STM32 and renaming the project but it didn't help. Screenshots below present errors and C/C++ properties.

[image: .]
[image: .]
[image: .]
[image: .]

Answer (score 0):

They are automatically generated makefiles anf you should not have been using it in this configuration. Change the generator to internal.